# R: modify a variable conditioned on data from multiple previous rows

Tags: r, if-statement, panel-data, dplyr

Hi I would really appreciate some help for this, I really couldn't find the solution in previous questions.

I have a tibble in long format (rows grouped by id and arranged by time). 
I want to create a variable "eleg" based on "varx". The condition would be that "eleg" = 1 if "varx" in the previous 3 rows == 0 and in the current row varx == 1, if not = 0, for each ID. If possible using dplyr.

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
time <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4)
varx <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1)
eleg <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
table <- data.frame(id, time, varx, eleg)
```

In my real dataset the condition is "in the previous 24 rows" and the same ID could have eleg == 1 more than one time if it suits the condition.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to do this by group of `id` or running through the entire df?

Comment: Thanks, by id! I will clarify that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the approach could be

```
library(dplyr)

m <- 3     #number of times previous rows are looked back

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(eleg = ifelse(rowSums(sapply(1:m, function(k) lag(varx, n = k, order_by = id, default = 1) == 0)) == m & varx == 1, 
                       1, 
                       0)) %>%
  data.frame()
```

which gives

```
   id time varx eleg
1   1    1    0    0
2   1    2    0    0
3   1    3    0    0
4   1    4    0    0
5   1    5    1    1
6   1    6    1    0
7   1    7    0    0
8   2    1    0    0
9   2    2    1    0
10  2    3    1    0
11  2    4    1    0
12  2    5    1    0
13  2    6    1    0
14  3    1    0    0
15  3    2    0    0
16  3    3    0    0
17  3    4    1    1
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 3), time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
1, 2, 3, 4), varx = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1)), .Names = c("id", "time", "varx"), row.names = c(NA, 
-17L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
df %>% 
mutate(elegnew = ifelse(Reduce("+", shift(df$varx, 1:3)) == 0 & df$varx == 1, 1, 0))

   id time varx eleg elegnew
1   1    1    0    0       0
2   1    2    0    0       0
3   1    3    0    0       0
4   1    4    0    0       0
5   1    5    1    1       1
6   1    6    1    0       0
7   1    7    0    0       0
8   2    1    0    0       0
9   2    2    1    0       0
10  2    3    1    0       0
11  2    4    1    0       0
12  2    5    1    0       0
13  2    6    1    0       0
14  3    1    0    0       0
15  3    2    0    0       0
16  3    3    0    0       0
17  3    4    1    1       1
```

Comment: Thanks, I `group_by(id)`  before `mutate` and worked!

Comment: Although for the rows were there was a 1 in the previous 3 rows it gives me `NA`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, using `dplyr` and `zoo`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(elegnew = as.integer(varx == 1 & 
                      rollsum(varx == 1, k = 4, align = "right", fill = 0) == 1))

# # A tibble: 17 x 5
# # Groups:   id [3]
# id  time  varx  eleg elegnew
# <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <int>
#   1    1.    1.    0.    0.       0
# 2    1.    2.    0.    0.       0
# 3    1.    3.    0.    0.       0
# 4    1.    4.    0.    0.       0
# 5    1.    5.    1.    1.       1
# 6    1.    6.    1.    0.       0
# 7    1.    7.    0.    0.       0
# 8    2.    1.    0.    0.       0
# 9    2.    2.    1.    0.       0
# 10    2.    3.    1.    0.       0
# 11    2.    4.    1.    0.       0
# 12    2.    5.    1.    0.       0
# 13    2.    6.    1.    0.       0
# 14    3.    1.    0.    0.       0
# 15    3.    2.    0.    0.       0
# 16    3.    3.    0.    0.       0
# 17    3.    4.    1.    1.       1
```

The idea is to group by id and then check a) whether varx is 1 and b) whether the sum of varx=1 events in the previous 3 plus current row (k=4) is 1 (which means all previous 3 must be 0). I assume that varx is either 0 or 1.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Also, thanks for the explanation, indeed varx is 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked for a `dplyr` solution, preferably.
The following is a base R one, with a function that you can adapt to *"in the previous 24 rows"*, just pass `n = 24` to the function.

```
fun <- function(DF, crit = "varx", new = "eleg", n = 3){
  DF[[new]] <- 0
  for(i in seq_len(nrow(DF))[-seq_len(n)]){
    if(all(DF[[crit]][(i - n):(i - 1)] == 0) && DF[[crit]][i] == 1)
      DF[[new]][i] <- 1
  }
  DF
}


sp <- split(table[-4], table[-4]$id)
new_df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(sp, fun))
row.names(new_df) <- NULL
identical(table, new_df)
#[1] TRUE
```

Note that if you are creating a new column, `eleg`, you would probably not need to split `table[-4]`, just `table` since the 4th column wouldn't exist yet.
You could do `do.call(rbind, lapply(sp, fun, n = 24))` and the rest would be the same.